# Change element order only when one element is empty or missing

Tags: xml, xslt

I have an XML workflow that is nearly complete. I have one issue left to resolve that my boss just threw at me, but I am stumped. The source XML contains four elements to display a bank's address and hours of operation: `<Address1>`, `<Address2>`, `<Zip>` and `<Hours>`.

When all elements are present and contain data the element order should appear as (A):

`<Address1>123 Main St</Address1> <Hours>M-F 9:00am-5:00pm</Hours><xsl:text>`
`</xsl:text><Address2>PO Box 2345</Address2> <Zip>60050</Zip>`

If `<Address2>` is missing or empty the order of the elements should be as (B):

`<Address1>123 Main St</Address1> <Zip>60050</Zip> <Hours>M-F 9:00am-5:00pm</Hours>`

Note how the Zip is now moved to appear after `<Address1>`. This is what is stumping me. I've tried using "choose" without success. Any suggestions?

Here is the current XSL:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE xsl:stylesheet>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:output method="xml"/>
<xsl:template match="/">

<Root>
<Story><xsl:apply-templates select="Root/Story/BK"/></Story>
</Root>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="BankName | Address1 | Hours | Established | RoutingNbr | CO/CityOfficePhone | CO/CityOfficeAddress2 "><xsl:element name="{name()}"><xsl:value-of select="."/></xsl:element></xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="BK">
<xsl:apply-templates select="BankName"/><xsl:text>  </xsl:text><xsl:apply-templates select="Established"/>    <xsl:text>    </xsl:text><xsl:apply-templates select="RoutingNbr"/><xsl:text>
</xsl:text>
<xsl:apply-templates select="OfficeOfLabel"/>
<xsl:apply-templates select="Address1"/><xsl:text>  </xsl:text><xsl:apply-templates select="Hours"/>
<xsl:apply-templates select="Address2"/><xsl:apply-templates select="Zip"/>
<xsl:apply-templates select="Phone"/><xsl:apply-templates select="Fax"/><xsl:text>
</xsl:text>

</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Address2[string-length() != 0]"><xsl:text>
</xsl:text><Address2><xsl:value-of select="."/></Address2><xsl:text>    </xsl:text>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Zip">
<Zip><xsl:value-of select="."/></Zip><xsl:text>
</xsl:text></xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Here is some sample XML:

```
<Root><Story><BK><BankName>Ames National Corporation</BankName><Established>Est. 1975</Established><RoutingNbr>8020-0135-0</RoutingNbr><Address1>405 5th Street</Address1><Hours>Hrs: M-F 8-5</Hours><Address2></Address2>      <Zip>50010</Zip><Fax>FAX: (515) 663-3033</Fax><Phone>(515) 232-6251</Phone><WebURL>Web: www.amesnational.com</WebURL><MultiBankLabel>Please see Multi-Bank Holding Companies section</MultiBankLabel>
</BK>
<BK><BankName>Bank of the West</BankName><Address1>525 Main</Address1><Zip>50010-6008</Zip><Fax>FAX: (515) 232-3791</Fax><Phone>(515) 232-8664</Phone><OfficeOfLabel>Office of Bank of the West, West Des Moines</OfficeOfLabel>
<EH><Employee>Michael Sondall, BM</Employee></EH>
</BK>
<BK><BankName>Bankers Trust Company</BankName><Address1>1510 Buckeye </Address1><Zip>50010</Zip><Phone>(515) 233-4424</Phone><WebURL>Web: www.bankerstrust.com</WebURL><OfficeOfLabel>Office of Bankers Trust Company, Des Moines</OfficeOfLabel>
<EH><Employee>John Russell, VP</Employee></EH>
</BK>
<BK><BankName>Exchange State Bank</BankName><RoutingNbr>0739-0950-7</RoutingNbr><Address1>823 Wheeler, Ste 32</Address1><Zip>50010</Zip><Fax>FAX: (515) 232-5068</Fax><Phone>(515) 232-5060</Phone><Email>e-Mail: ames@esb1.com</Email><OfficeOfLabel>Office of Exchange State Bank, Collins</OfficeOfLabel>
<EH><Employee>Allison Appel, VP, CPA</Employee></EH><EH><Employee>Christine Heintz, AVP</Employee></EH>
</BK>
<BK><BankName>First American Bank</BankName><Established>Est. 1956</Established><RoutingNbr>0739-0080-7</RoutingNbr><Address1>1530 S Duff Avenue, Ste 1</Address1><Hours>Hrs: M-TH 9-5 SAT 8-12</Hours><Address2>        </Address2><Zip>50010</Zip><Fax>FAX: (515) 956-3160</Fax><Phone>(515) 233-2033</Phone><WebURL>Web: </WebURL>        <OfficeOfLabel>Office of First American Bank, Fort Dodge</OfficeOfLabel>
<EH><Employee>Steve Goodhue, Reg Pres</Employee></EH>
</BK></Story</Root>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Use**:

```
 <xsl:apply-templates select="Address1"/>
 <xsl:apply-templates select="Zip[not(string(../Address2))]"/>
 <xsl:apply-templates select="Hours"/>
 <xsl:apply-templates select="Address2[string()]"/>
 <xsl:apply-templates select="Zip[string(../Address2)]"/>

** Edited by MHK to add "../" in two lines above
```

**Explanation**:

1. When `Address2` is present and has a non-empty string value, then the above sequence of instructions applies templates to: `Address1`, `Hours`, `Address2` and `Zip`  and the corresponding results are generated in this sequence -- exactly as wanted.
2. When `Address2` is absent or has empty string value, then the above sequence of instructions applies templates to: `Address1`, `Zip` and `Hours`,  and the corresponding results are generated in this sequence -- again exactly as wanted.

Comment: I will try this immediately. Thanks

Comment: This technique did not work for me. It never produces the `Address2` element. In some cases the data from `Address2` appears, but never the tag itself

Comment: I'm sorry, I tried this again and got a completely different result. Using your suggestion with the following template:

`<xsl:template match="Address2[string-length() != 0]"><xsl:text>`
`</xsl:text><Address2><xsl:value-of select="."/></Address2>`  `<xsl:text>    </xsl:text>`
`</xsl:template>`

I do get the `Address2` element, but I never get the Zip following it. Zip always appears after Address1.

Comment: A rare mistake from Dimitre, which I have corrected. The Address2 elements are siblings of the Zip element so it's necessary to use ../Address2 within the predicate.

Comment: @MichaelKay: Thank you, I must have been tired last night when I posted this answer -- just before going to sleep.

Comment: @JimMaivald: Sorry, I was working late last evening. With the correction by Michael Kay this solution should now be OK.